# Making systemctl to shutdown process gracefully

Tags: services, systemd

I made a small systemctl service to manqge HLTV server (it records demos from a game and stores them on disk):

```
[Unit]
Description=HLTV server
Requires=cs16.service
After=cs16.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=cs16
Group=cs16
UMask=007

ExecStart=/home/cs16/server/hltv_start.sh

Restart=on-failure

# Configures the time to wait before service is stopped forcefully.
TimeoutStopSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It works great, but if I shutdown/restart system service, it kills the process, which corrupts demo that is currently being written.

To properly save the demo, I need to type "quit" or "stop" in htlv command tool.
Is there a way to make systemctl send one of those commands to the program before closing it?

Comment: Or alternatively, if a special signal can be sent, that can be configured to be used as the stop signal.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I think if I store the process in `screen` or `tmux`, I can later send stdin into it.

Comment: I have the same question, did you find a solution to this question?

Comment: I would recommend contacting the vendor of HLTV server and requesting them to implement support for SIGTERM. It's common UNIX logic that process is sent SIGTERM when it should do graceful shutdown. It appears that HLTV server causes corrupted files when it receives this signal, which is obviously not the correct way to handle that signal.

Answer (score 14):

By default, if you `systemctl stop` a process, systemd sends SIGTERM to the process.  That process is responsible for handling the signal and shutting down gracefully.  If the process does not shutdown within 90 seconds, SIGKILL will forcefully stop the process.

There are several ways to change this default behaviour:

- `ExecStop=`: If your process would normally shutdown via an external signal from a socket, shared-memory, touched file, you can execute a script that sends that to your process using `ExecStop=`.
- `KillSignal=`: If your process doesn't respond well to SIGTERM, you can change which signal is sent to the process using `KillSignal=`.  Maybe your process responds better to SIGINT, SIGABRT, or SIGQUIT.  Note that this signal should initiate the save that your program will perform.
- `TimeoutStopSec=`, This defaults to 90s, giving that time between the first `KillSignal` and `FinalKillSignal`.  I see you've already increased this to 300s.  If your saves normally take longer than this, increase it.  If that's more than you'd expect for a save, then your process is probably not responding to your current `KillSignal=`.
- `SendSIGKILL=`: If your process does start the save, but you want to wait indefinatley, you can set this to `no` to let the service hang forever.  (Play with `TimeoutStopSet` first).
- `FinalKillSignal=`: If your killsignal didn't work well and you want to followup after `TimeoutStopSet` with something other than `SIGKILL` you can set that code here.

---

Think about how you would normally stop the process if you weren't running that as a service.  Then emulate that.  Do you use `CTRL+D` in a terminal?  Do you `kill` the process?

Since your process was started with `ExecStart=/home/cs16/server/hltv_start.sh`, maybe you want `ExecStop=/home/cs16/server/hltv_stop.sh`.

> To properly save the demo, I need to type "quit" or "stop" in htlv command tool.

Is this command-tool a command-line application? If so, maybe you just need:

```
ExecStop=/home/cs16/server/hltv_command_tool.sh -c stop
```

If this tool is part of the HLTV GUI you might be able to send the `quit` or `stop` text by sending text via your window manager. The following command runs a `bash` shell, then uses `xdotool` to search for a window with `hltv` in the title. Then it will type `quit` into that window and then it will press `Enter`:

```
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c 'xdotool type --window "$(xdotool search hltv | head -1)" quit && xdotool key --window "$(xdotool search hltv | head -1)" Enter'
```

Answer (score 2):

## It shouldn't be a service

Something that can't be terminated without causing catastrophic damage to its operation shouldn't be run as a "service", but as a per-job script or process.

What you're attempting would compare to waiting for the Internet to stop requesting from your website before allowing `systemctl stop apache2` to complete itself.

For a local machine, if you need to shut down the machine, you won't be able to continue writing the file anyway. If you decided to do that, then you *want* `systemctl` to end the service without waiting.

### Maybe, your service should run another script that waits to terminate.

The solution will be in your Product Roadmap, viz letting the developers tell the Product Manager what user experience isn't possible and what the user should experience instead.

---

I'm answering this with the following suggestions, not knowing the contents of your script `hltv_start.sh` because you didn't share it. So, it must not be central to your question. Accordingly, I can't be specific much beyond these brainstorms...

---

Consider:

- Take a scripted approach to what Kdenlive does in GUI, similar to to the option of shutting down the machine once finished rendering. You could adapt a scropt to start writing your file, then automatically shut down your service via `systemctl stop` *after* you finish writing your file.
- Make a script to write your file on a per-job basis using `wait` to let the write process finish before exiting.
- Write a separate script using `systemctl` to end that process as a kind of power-move that **should** stop the process mid-file.
- If you need a service involved, use it to "listen" or something, not to actually write—a service that calls a script that uses `wait` to end, if even necessary.
- If the service only "listens", then runs another script that writes your file using `wait`, then you could theoretically `systemctl stop` your service while allowing the write operation to finish, which I think is your goal.